# Importing jsforce in typescript react application results in error

Tags: typescript, react-redux, jsforce

I'm using react function based components with typescript - webpack version 5.74
importing jsforce is resulting in the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
    at _inherits (index.js:43:107)
    at index.js:92:1
    at ./node_modules/csv-parse/lib/es5/index.js (index.js:1386:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/jsforce/lib/csv.js (csv.js:4:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/jsforce/lib/record-stream.js (record-stream.js:15:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
```

Typescript Class:

```
import jsforce from "jsforce";

const generateAuthUrl = () => {
  const oAuth2 = jsforce.OAuth2(loginUrl, clientId, redirectUri);
  ...
}
```

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling jsforce, overriding the version of csv-parse and importing jsforce directly before I use it in my function

Any thoughts as to what is going wrong here, would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am encountering the same issue with this package, but for Angular.

Comment: I was not. I found a way to do what I needed manually.

Comment: Can you share how you did this manually?